# C# - does Task.FromResult incur a heavy penalty?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm a bit new to `async` coding with `C#`, and have encountered a few places where methods I have to implement (either from an interface or part of an inherited service, or just suggested default convention) are marked `async` and expect a `Task<T>` return.

But I don't always have async code to run; I don't always have something that needs an `await` operator.

So my ad-hoc workaround is to just return `await Task.FromResult({normal code});` to these kinds of methods, like this...

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Id() {
    // if the user is not authenticated, simply return false
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || String.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
        return await Task.FromResult(Json(false));
    return await Task.FromResult((Json(User?.FindFirst("users/id")?.Value ?? null)));
}
```

This does solve the compile time errors, but I was wondering if there is an inherit problem with doing this. If so, what are good methods for getting around things marked as `async` that I cannot change?

Comment: Don't mark the method as `async` if you have nothing to await.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `Task.FromResult` in your context, it has been designed (among many other reasons) to solve issues such as the one you are having. But in your case above there is no need to `await` your tasks, just return them and remove the `async`

Comment: Even if the return type is marked `Task<T>`?

Comment: Even if return type is `int` one does not need `Int.Parse(42.ToString())`... Not sure why you think `Task<T>` is special in any way.

Comment: @Ciel, Yes, whenever you add `async` to a method that returns a `Task` you are asking `.NET` to turn your method into a state machine which executes a piece of logic `AFTER` your asynchronous method. Here all you want to do is to return the task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating a `Task`, then adding a continuation to that task that does literally noting but wrap it in an identical `Task`, just *return the first task that you created*.

Since you have nothing to `await`, there is no reason for the method to be marked as `async`.

Considering the performance costs of `FromResult` is a pointless discussion.  You need to create a task based on the result that you have, so that work needs to be done.  Considering how expensive it is is irrelevant as you have no alternative options.  You could try to create your own `FromResult` method if you think you can write one that'll perform better than Microsoft's version.

That said, no, it is not particularly expensive of an operation.